# how does django ORM handle thousands of concurrent requests as it is synchronous?

Tags: django, django-orm

As Django ORM is a synchronous piece of code and django is WSGI based, then how it serve thousands of concurrent request at a time.

Comment: It is the database that needs to handle concurrent updates. If the number of concurrent requests is high, and likely to collide, then usually transactions are used.

Comment: okay. Then if thousands of requests hit ORM  at a time, and we know ORM is Synchronus then how the request served by the ORM.

Comment: I think you focus too much on the ORM. An ORM is just something that translates your queryset in a database query, and parses the results. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: You are right my concern is ORM here.

Comment: but where would you let two threads work on the *same* `QuerySet`? Usually in your views, you will each time construct new `QuerySet`s. Furthermore a `QuerySet` is usually handled in a "functional" way, where each time a variant is constructed, not updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Then would you please explain how django synchronus ORM serve asynchronus requests in ASGI.

Comment: synchronous means that you can not let two threads operate on the *same* queryset object. But that does not mean you can not let two views (threads) work on different querysets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200813/discussion-between-sharif-42-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 4):

**`Django`** is synchronous but we do not define ORM concurrent request based on that. It is database that need to handle concurrent requests.

If you use connection pooling or use multiple connection to database of some sort then we say concurrent requests handling. There comes commits to table. Every changes in db we say transactions, and in every transaction there can be multiple commits. Commits are synchronous to keep db integrity.

To understand database working with schema please read this [Post](https://hakibenita.com/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models)

Comment: Then would you please explain how django synchronus ORM serve asynchronus requests in ASGI.